# VBA Ado query didn't bring data which containst letters

Tags: excel, vba, database

I have got a small app that brings data from a different Excel file. It successfully brings all the data those are contain numbers. But sometimes there are data which are contains letters too. For example:
generally the column has data like following (this data should be in same column I can't change it):

```
2023232023
2023242024
and sometimes
2023AE2023
```

When there are letters like this it won't return this data.

```
dim conn as variant

conn = "select [city],[xData] fromt [mainSheet$] where[case] = 0"
rs.Open conn, connectionn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPressimistic
```

I think these are the relevant parts of my codes. What I should do to bring data which contains letters too. Is it possible ?

I am trying to make a small Excel program

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are applying a [WHERE clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) and your query will bring only cities and xdata if the field case is zero (as number). Check the value of that field in the missing rows and probably your problem is there. Also, try without applying WHERE to bring all data

Answer (score 1):

When you use ADODB to query an Excel sheet, the sheet acts like a table in a database. In a real database you specify the data type of all columns, eg `String` or `Number` or `Date`.

In Excel, there is no data type specification and Excel needs to guess. As your data contains mainly numeric data, it assumes that the column is numeric and returns numbers for that column. As there are no mixed data type columns, it will return null for a value that is not numeric.

As your data is obviously not numeric (but contains mainly strings that look like a number), you should tell Excel so. The easiest way is to format the column as `Text` - then the Engine will assume string as data type and return also the columns that contain text